# Create list of Time Interval Swift

Tags: ios, swift, time, intervals

Hello I have trouble creating a list of regular time interval starting from a time until arriving to another. Can you help me? (Swift 2.0)

Example:

I have two times (8:00 - 23:00). I know the duration of the interval (30 minutes). The scope is to create an Array of intervals of time (8: 00-8: 30, 8:30 - 9: 00 etc). I use an object call Time(start:Int, end:Int)

Thank you

Answer (score 9):

You could create a class like this to generate the intervals like that,

```
struct Time {

    let start: TimeInterval
    let end: TimeInterval
    let interval: TimeInterval

    init(start: TimeInterval, interval: TimeInterval, end: TimeInterval) {
        self.start = start
        self.interval = interval
        self.end = end
    }

    init(startHour: TimeInterval, intervalMinutes: TimeInterval, endHour: TimeInterval) {
        self.start = startHour * 60 * 60
        self.end = endHour * 60 * 60
        self.interval = intervalMinutes * 60
    }

    var timeRepresentations: [String] {
        let dateComponentFormatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
        dateComponentFormatter.unitsStyle = .positional
        dateComponentFormatter.allowedUnits = [.minute, .hour]

        var dateComponent = DateComponents()
        return timeIntervals.map { timeInterval in
            dateComponent.second = Int(timeInterval)
            return dateComponentFormatter.string(from: dateComponent)!
        }
    }

    var timeIntervals: [TimeInterval]{
        return Array(stride(from: start, through: end, by: interval))
    }
}
```

You could then generate array of time representations,

```
let time = Time(startHour: 8, intervalMinutes: 30, endHour: 23)

print(time.timeRepresentations)
```

And that generates,

> ["8:00", "8:30", "9:00", "9:30", "10:00", "10:30", "11:00", "11:30",
>   "12:00", "12:30", "13:00", "13:30", "14:00", "14:30", "15:00",
>   "15:30", "16:00", "16:30", "17:00", "17:30", "18:00", "18:30",
>   "19:00", "19:30", "20:00", "20:30", "21:00", "21:30", "22:00",
>   "22:30", "23:00"]

And to retrieve the ranges, put this code at the end

```
let time = Time(startHour: 9, intervalMinutes: 30, endHour: 17)

let ranges = time.timeRepresentations.enumerated().compactMap { index, value -> String? in
    if index + 1 < time.timeRepresentations.count {
        return value + " - " + time.timeRepresentations[index + 1]
    }
    return nil
}

print(ranges.joined(separator: "\n"))
```

And the result would be ,

```
9:00 - 9:30
9:30 - 10:00
10:00 - 10:30
10:30 - 11:00
11:00 - 11:30
11:30 - 12:00
12:00 - 12:30
12:30 - 13:00
13:00 - 13:30
13:30 - 14:00
14:00 - 14:30
14:30 - 15:00
15:00 - 15:30
15:30 - 16:00
16:00 - 16:30
16:30 - 17:00
```

Comment: ok, If I want to create an array of two times (ex: ["8:00-8:30", "8:30-9:00"]), where I must modify?

Comment: I am still trying to understand the code above. It works, but i dont understand it

Comment: What did you not understand ?

Comment: Never mind. I got it now. I just never saw the `stride` command before. I new to swift. It took me a while to understand it.

Answer (score 0):

you can create an schedule timer like this in your viewDidLoad method but first define a selector to your method call,

```
    let mySelector: Selector = "time:end:"
    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.4, target: self, selector: mySelector, userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
```

and then define your time method

```
func time(start: Int, end: Int) {
    // code goes here, this method will called every 30 minutes.
}
```

so now you can create a list and add the start and end params.

Answer (score 0):

The simple array containing tuple of start-end

```
let startDate = NSDate()
let endDate = NSDate()

var intervalsContainer = [(start: NSDate, end: NSDate)]()

var intervalDate = startDate;


var dateComponents30Min = NSDateComponents()
dateComponents30Min.minute = 30

let calendar = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()

while(endDate.compare(intervalDate) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending) {
    let finDate = calendar.dateByAddingComponents(dateComponents30Min, toDate: intervalDate, options: [])!
    intervalsContainer.append((intervalDate,finDate))
    intervalDate = finDate
}
```

Comment: What I must modify if the end time is after the midnight?

Comment: ok, thank's. 
 
What I must modify If I want to hide times before current time?

Comment: You have to enter proper start and end date

Comment: the problem was that I use finDate.compare(NSDate()) == NSComparisonResult.OrderedDescending but not work

Comment: let startDate = NSDate()

enter here the minimum date, you want to calculate from

Comment: The problem is that I have only the start time and end time, and I can not change it, I have to hide times before the time today